# Using contrasting words "merit" and "demerit" in a sentence

Tags: word-usage

> The iPad mini seems to have many **merits**, but you would not find out its **demerits** until you have used it a lot.

Could I use this sentence in an essay?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, *to has many* must be changed to *to have many.*

According to the [Oxford dictionary online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/demerit?q=demerit), *demerit* does still mean *disadvantage* in British English; however, in North American English it has a more specific meaning (from the same link): "a mark awarded against someone for a fault or offence". That meaning does not make sense in your sentence.

The better pairs of words in a North American English context are *pluses/minuses, advantages/disadvantages*, *good points/bad points,* or *upside/downside* (the latter pair are uncountable).  Another antonym for *advantage* is *drawback,* and I quite like that one, too.

As well, the latter half of your sentence, *you would not find out its demerits until you have used it a lot,* is not natural. The modal verb *would* is not appropriate as you have used it.  I would suggest the following two possible revisions: (1) *but after using it a lot, you will discover its drawbacks,* or (2) *but if you used it a lot, you would discover its drawbacks.*  The difference between *will* and *would* in my revision is that using *will* shows that you are likely to buy an iPad, whereas *would* makes the possibility seem less likely.  Of the two suggested revisions, #1 is the most applicable, I think, because of the stronger likelihood that it implies.

Comment: Right, I realised the mistake the word "has" should be "have" after it was posted. And thanks for pointing out other issues of the sentence.

Comment: I can't avoid noticing that OP's original said you wouldn't become aware of the iPad's shortcomings *until you have **used it a lot***, whereas both your paraphrasings say you will ***soon*** find them. Arguably, in trying to illustrate what we *normally* say in such contexts, you're lost the thrust of the original, which is more along the lines of *"The iPad initially seems great - but the more you use it, the more you become aware of its bad points"*.

Comment: @ShawnMooney, Right - FumbleFingers' comments about your two revisions hit the points. Further, you don't have to buy one actually, instead anyone may experience it by using a borrowed one. So, what changes are needed to make it sound natural and also keep the thrust?

Comment: Great comments!  I have revised my post accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

This is primarily a question about personal preference because it's about style (word choice), not grammar. OTOH, it is about usage (word choice). If you read reviews of computer hardware, you'll see that the writers rarely use those two words. They mostly talk about the **pros** and **cons**, or the **positives** & **negatives**. *Merits* & *demerits* sound too much like the Boy Scouts. **Advantages** & **disadvantages** might also be a reasonable pair of words to choose for describing the **strengths** & **weaknesses** of the iPad Mini.

Comment: _Pros and cons_ are sometimes spelled _pro's and con's_.

Comment: @bytebuster: Yes, they are sometimes spelled that way. I don't think about that kind of stuff, though, because it's inconsistent. Some people punctuate "The 1980s" as "The 1980's". Because I'm willing to say that there are no hard & fast rules in English these days (not that there ever were, mind you, despite the Herculean efforts expended by the 18th-, 19th-, & 20th-century prescriptivist grammarians to set a bunch of rules in concrete), I'm also willing to mentally edit what I read so that I can understand it.

Comment: @bytebuster That would be incorrect, though, because the apostrophe indicates possession where there is none.  Also in Bill's example, where people say "The 1980's", that is also wrong--again possession where there is none. So when people do that just try to ignore it, as Bill also suggested--it's one of those rules that even native speakers don't always get right, just like "its" and "it's". :)

Comment: @WendiKidd I can't agree. _Pro_ is a Latin preposition deliberately used as noun. _Con_ is a **truncated** Latin preposition _contra_. An apostrophe here indicates that it's plural for a non-that-much-noun, rather an abbreviation, quite like _DJ's_ (versus _disk jockeys_) or _LtCol's_ (versus _Lieutenant Colonels_).

Comment: @bytebuster *DJ's* would mean "belonging to the DJ" while "DJs" would mean "more than one DJ". "LtCol's" would mean "belonging to the Lieutenant Colonel", while "LtCols" would mean "more than one Lieutenant Colonel". The apostrophes denote possession. ie. "The DJs took my DJ's bag!"  Meaning more than one DJ took the bag belonging to my DJ.

Comment: As [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pro%27s+and+cons%2Cpros+and+cons&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) shows, Bill is firmly in the majority camp with *pros and cons*. But it's a different story with [p's and q's](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=p%27s+and+q%27s%2Cps+and+qs&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=)